# Handle html elements in print mode

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have the following page in **print mode** I want the top section (encircled in black) to only appear on the first page as I have 3 pages. So far the header is appearing on all 3 pages and I wanna know how I can do that with JQuery and CSS. All I tried so far didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the section about providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

To make the top section (header) appear only on the first page when printing, you can use CSS and the `@media print` rule along with the `:first-child` selector. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Print Page</title>
  <style>
    @media print {
      /* Hide header on all pages except the first page */
      .header:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <!-- Your header content here -->
    <h1>Header Content</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Rest of your page content here -->
  <p>Page content goes here...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, the CSS rule inside `@media print` targets the `.header` element that is not the first child, and sets its `display` property to `none`, effectively hiding it on all pages except the first page when printing.